# How do i read a text files lines and remove the first line?

Tags: c#, .net

```
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt");
foreach (string file in files)
{

}
```

I want to to remove from the file UploadedVideoFiles.txt the first line.

Comment: You'll want to investigate the `File.WriteAllLines()` provided by `System.IO` as well. Just make an array of all of the lines you read in and skip the first - you can use `.Skip(1)` and `.ToArray()` to help out

Comment: I forgot to mention that i want to update the text file after removing the first line. Skip(1) will update the text file on hard disk ?

Comment: No, it won't. Consider using the @imlokesh solution.

Comment: No - you'll need to `Skip(1)`, which will give you an `IEnumerable<string>` in memory of the file, minus the first line. If you turn it into an array using `.ToArray()`, you can then write it back to disk using `File.WriteAllLines()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Enumerable.Skip Linq extension method:

```
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt").Skip(1).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt", files);
```

Comment: I'd materialize the file only once, either bei removing the `ToArray` call or by switching to `File.ReadLines`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The `ToArray` is required because `File.WriteAllLines` requires a string array for the content parameter and the `Skip` method returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which cannot be automatically cast to `Array`. Whether `ReadLines` or `ReadAllLines` is used makes no difference, the whole file must be read and either method will read the file only once in this case.

Comment: [`File.WriteAllLines(string, IEnumerable<string>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx) exists since .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ is the best approach in this case:

```
foreach (string file in files.Skip(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt");
File.WriteAllLines(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt", lines.Skip(1));
```

Comment: Looks incorrect to me. Since the same file is used for input and output, your lazy reading code will prevent it from being opened for writing.

Comment: I just tested it, and as predicted, it does not work. It would work if you wrote the output to a file different from the one you're reading.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to test... It works with `ReadAllLines` and that's what I intended to use in first place. Sorry if I offended you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Old school (without LINQ) is to start iterating at index 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i < files.Length; ++i)
{
   // do something with files[i], which is a line in the file.
}
```